# Principles of how to avoid troubles between django test server and production environment?

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I'm constantly hassled by the difference between django test server and apache/wsgi production environment. Perfectly working code in a test server always fails after deployment, and debugging often seems impossibly hard. This time it cannot even find `django.db.models` :,(

template

```
{{one_medal_owningship.get_medal_name}}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class MedalsManager(models.Manager):
    _cache={}

    def get_by_owningship(self,owningship):
        return self.__class__._cache[owningship.medal_id]
    ...

class Medals(models.Model):
    name=models.Charfield(max_length=50)
    objects=MedalsManager()
    ...

class MedalOwningship(models.Model):
    medal=models.ForeignKey('app.Medals')
    user=models.ForeignKey('auth.User')

    def get_medal_name(self):
        return models.get_model("app","Medal").objects.get_by_owningship(self).name #Here is ***the problem***, models is reported as None

import signal_listeners  #I put signal listeners in a separated file and register them here
```

signal_listeners.py

```
# site_settings.py is a file in the root of the project for storing some control variables, like the number of posts you can post a day
import site_settings #This is the "cause" of the problem, if I change it to myproject.site_settings then everything works.
```

Searching around the internet about this often leads to very specific cases that're hard to get a full picture from. I'm wondering if there's any rules of thumbs about how these troubles should be avoided, any reading list or tutorials? And could the setting up of server environment potentially lead to unnecessary errors in code(say the django and python version is identical as development environment)? Thanks very much!

**Update:**
I get the problem solved somehow but not knowing the cause. So in the code above, an error is raised when `a_medal_owningship.get_medal_name` is executed, apparently the `django.db.models` becomes `None` in that function's scope. In that models.py file I imported a signal_listener file. If I change how site_settings(a customized constant storage) is imported in signal_listeners from `import site_settings` to `import myproject.site_settings`, the problem get solved.

However if I import another random file from the project root, like `import foobar`, there wouldn't be any problems. So it must be the site_settings get imported somewhere else together with being imported here leads to the problem.

This makes no sense to me, as how can importing a customized file conflicts with django's default modules? And what's the difference between `import foo` and `import myproject.foo`?

Comment: Your question is completely unclear and vague. I do not have general issues between dev server and apache and I do not perceive it as a general problem in the community. What is your specific error, what does your environemnt look like? And then you might get some help!

Comment: None of these issues have *anything at all* to do with run server vs modwsgi.

Comment: Hello @DanielRoseman, do you have any speculation about what could be the causes? And I'm sorry it's quite hard to describe the problem specifically as the problem scope is yet to be defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differences between the development server and mod_wsgi, and now gunicorn when run against wsgi.py direct, are a common theme that keeps reoccuring. It is indeed a problem that is hard to describe and is dissappointing when people try and dismiss it as an issue just because they haven't experienced it. It is a real problem, and if you hang around helping people on the forums long enough you will see it a fair bit.

Although I don't use Django myself, I have tried a few times to understand the problem so can better explain to people what the issue is, but even then haven't got a simple answer.

I have blogged about the problem before in:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html

The basic problem boils do to the fact that the development server, by virtue of management commands being loaded will preload large parts of your Django application and does it in a certain order.

In mod_wsgi and gunicorn, when you don't use run_gunicorn management command for gunicorn case, things are instead lazily loaded and this can cause problems as bits can be loaded in any order based on order requests come in for different parts of the application.

The underlying cause for all the problems tends to always be the order in which you perform module imports, especially where you have cyclical module imports. Missing imports can also be an issue.

So there are real problems. Hard to track down but pay particular attention to module imports. It seems to happen quite a lot in relation to models for some reason.

Whether that is your issue or not, is a different question, but yes, people do see differences between development server and production deployments.

To investigate further would need actual error messages to be added to your question.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamDumpleton! I think the "lazy loading" is exactly what's costing me headaches. I got the problem solved somehow but the real cause is still unknown: the way I solved it just didn't make much sense to me. I tried to boil down the problem a bit but not sure if it's going to help much. 

Sadly there's no silver bullet for this type of problems, and in this case developing in test server seems not relevant to reality anymore, why should we be developing in total darkness and find out the problem much later? Maybe it's a better idea of ditch it once for all.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, this is a very general question, though it really depends a lot on how your production environment differs from the development environment. Since my first server hassles and now I somehow made my own rules how to deploy without hassle. Even though when I make my initial deploy to the server (first deploy of the application) I most certainly always run into some problem. After that its becoming easier.

1. Keep settings seperated for dev und production environment. There are bunch of examples on how to do this without much work.
2. Use Fabric (or other automatic deployment). If you run into a problem in your server you can most of the time modify your fab script in order to not run into this problem next time again. Be it a `chmod` somehwere, a `south migrate`, install additional dependencies etc.. You can also handle different environments and simply make a local test for everything first.